# android - how to update the theme not in the onCreate event?

Tags: android, colors, themes, spinner

In my android app, I set the theme like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ThemeSetterActivity.setStyle(Main_MenuActivity.this); // this just calls context.setTheme();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
}
```

But how do I change the theme using

```
ThemeSetterActivity.setStyle(Main_MenuActivity.this);
```

when it's in the onresume event. When I try it, it does call the function but the theme doesn't change. Does it have something to do with not calling:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the theme of your application during run time, you can use the `setTheme(...)` method within the activity. You must set the theme to an activity, before loading the views of that activity.

For more info and implementation, [refer the link](http://www.anddev.org/applying_a_theme_to_your_application-t817.html):

**Updated**

And, as per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme%28int%29) to set theme you need to restart the entire activity.
You can try this code in `onResume()` of your activity,

```
Intent i = getIntent();
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```