# PreferenceActivity theme background not changing

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

My application has a function that changes between a light and dark theme based on user selection from the settings menu. This works fine except for the settings menu. When on the dark theme it only changes the text and not the background and action bar. I added a picture of what the dark screen looks like. Why is it doing this?

Edit: Code for theme changing. Theme is called at the begin of on create.

```
public static void theme(Activity activity) {
        if (userChoice==true)activity.setTheme(R.style.HoloDark);
        else if (userChoice==false)activity.setTheme(R.style.HoloLight);
    }

public void loadPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        boolean test = settings.getBoolean("nightmode", false);
        settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(MainActivity.this);
        if (test == true)userChoice=true;
        else if (test == false)userChoice=false;        
    }
```

[image: Settings Menu]

Comment: It would help us understand the issue if you would post also some code (how do you change the theme). I suspect you must do some sort of refresh that is not needed in other activities since you are creating them when you navigate to them.

Comment: I'll second @Laviniux on the refresh thing, also post some code so we can help you

Comment: OK I added the code I use

Comment: The problem is that onCreate is called only once (when the activity is created). You could restart the activity (to force it changing the theme in onCreate) after changing the theme. Please also see this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876094/android-how-to-update-the-theme-not-in-the-oncreate-event Another approach would be to manually do the changes if they are not too many (e.g. change the background), since restarting the activity is not very efficient.

Comment: The theme changes correctly. The problem is the theme is only affect the text.

Comment: That helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15656284/442204